# how to create a lambda layer for iris and its dependencies?

Tags: netcdf, aws-lambda-layers, iris-dataset, python-iris

I want to process `netCDF` files inside an AWS lambda function and I need to use `iris`. My plan is to create a lambda layer that has `iris` and it's dependencies installed. I am able to create a layer but its always complaining for a missing package when I run my lambda. I add the missing package to the layer and it complains for another. Does anybody know all the dependencies that `iris` needs to run successfully inside a lambda function? Appreciate any help.